# what is stored in lock.mdb file of LMDB database

Tags: caffe, lmdb

While I use caffe, I convert my images to LMDB file as input dataset. I got two files after I convert into LMDB format. One is data.mdb, which I figured should be where the data stored. The other one, lock.mdb, I wonder what is in this file and what it uses for?

Comment: It is used to control the concurrent access to the data files. See https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/3daab3be733b933a3fd2263441da4976206b27a2/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L2915

Comment: @AlexKreimer why not expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @shai will this help caffe not to die?

Comment: @AlexKreimer I like caffe, just wish they could have better documentation. But I did hear that Facebook has caffe2